# Using importXML function to get sector data of stock

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use importXML to get an automatic sector update and industry for my stocks in google sheets. In this case, in cell A5, is the name of the ticker. Normally, I would expect the following website:

https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=AAPL

Where instead of AAPL, I wish to insert "A5"

Furthermore, I wish to receive the "Information Technology" in one formula and "Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals" in another subheading.

The formula I have created is the following:

=ALS(ISLEEG(A5);"";importxml("https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/goto/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=​"&A5;"/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[3]/div[8]"))

It is however, not working, can someone please help me?

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of `Information Technology` and `Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals`.
- In the case of `https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=AAPL`, you want to retrieve, the values of `Sector (GICS®)` and `Industry (GICS®)`.

In this case, I thought that the values might be able to be retrieved by a xpath. The sample xpath is as follows.

#### Sample xpath:

```
//div[@class='sub-heading']//h3[../span/a[text()='Information Technology' or text()='Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals']]
```

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1;"//div[@class='sub-heading']//h3[../span/a[text()='Information Technology' or text()='Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals']]")
```

- In this case, the URL of `https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=AAPL` is put in the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

- When you want to put the values to the columns, in this case, please use `TRANSPOSE`.

#### Note:

- This xpath is for the URL of `https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=AAPL`. So when you change the URL, the values you expect might not be able to be retrieved. So please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post. This is however, not my goal. I will try to rephrase it and use a screenshot to elaborate: https://www.udrop.com/9gbX/sector.jpg 

So as you can see in the screenshot, my goal is to create a spreadsheet, where in the "A" colomn is written the name of the ticker of the stock, for example AAPL for apple, in the second colum, automatically comes the sector and in the third column the industry. I hope to do this automatically, so that the formula can be used for all tickers instead of creating a unique link for every ticker.

Comment: So my first idea was to use the following link:
https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=AAPL

But instead of adding "AAPL", I want to use "A2".
Then I want to retrieve the value of 'sector' in B2 and 'industry' in C2

Comment: @pashtun Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. When I saw your question, I couldn't understand that you wanted the table of https://www.udrop.com/9gbX/sector.jpg . This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. But, unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about the values you want. I apologize for this. Can you provide your result output values you expect and also the URLs you want to use? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @pashtun `=IMPORTXML("https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols="&A5,"//div[@class='sub-heading']//h3[../span/a[text()='Information Technology' or text()='Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals']]")`  // Tanaike, OP just wanted to construct the URL dynamically too

Comment: @iansedano Thank you for your comment. I couldn't notice about it. When that is the solution of OP's question, I'm glad. Thank you for your support. I would like to study more.

Comment: @pashtun can you confirm?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you very much for your reply, even though your english is not perfect, I appreciate the effort
iansedano Thank you very much for your help, I managed to edit your formula and get the one I desired.

For sector:
=IMPORTXML("https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols="&A2;"/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[3]/div[8]/span")

For industry:
=IMPORTXML("https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols="&A2;"/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[3]/div[13]/span")

Comment: @iansedano See my comment above, thanks again for the help

Comment: @pashtun Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about the values you want. I apologize for this. Can you provide your result output values you expect and also the URLs you want to use? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @pashtun - I understand that your issue is resolved. If that is the case you should accept Tanaike's answer as it was his work that mainly solved the problem, I just adapted his formula.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you sir the issue is resolved thanks to your. Thanks again!

Comment: @iansedano Thank you for comment. I couldn't notice that OP's issue had been resolved. From your comment, I could understand it. I'm glad for it. And, thank you for your support.